# foreach — iterating over two lists

Tags: lists

I need to iterate over two lists:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm, y=5mm]
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,8} {
        \node[] at (\x, 0) {value};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The "value" has to be a value from the second list: {2, 3, 5, 7, 11} (yes, these are first five prime numbers).

I know, TeX is not really a programming language, but is there a way to do so?

Nesting foreach doesn't solve the problem:

```
\foreach \x in {0,2,...,8} {
    \foreach \value in {2,3,5,7,11} {
        \node[] at (\x, 0) {\value};
    }
}
```

The output looks as expected like this:

[image: output]

Solution (thank you Pier Paolo):

```
\foreach \x/\value in {0/2,2/3,4/5,6/7,8/11} {
    \node[] at (\x, 0) {\value};
}
```

Comment: If your list is relatively short you could go with: `\foreach \x/\value in {0/2,2/3,4/5,6/7,8/11} \node at (\x,0) {\value};`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. Will I get performance problems while compiling with longer lists?

Comment: I don't think performance would be an issue, but this way you have to _manually_ input all entries (i.e., all the values that the control variable can assume in the loop) and cannot use the `...` facility to automatically compute the step and insert all missing values between first and last.

Comment: You cannot nest foreach for this example to work. The result is correct because for each `x` value all the `\value` values are evaluated. Hence @PierPaolo's solution is not an alternative it is the only correct one.