# iterating over multiple variables with \foreach it TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Note: I'm aware of another response [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245950/foreach-iterating-over-two-lists), but its solution was a quick-fix rather than the underlying issue.

Say I want to create the following diagram but using iteration:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {1/10,2/11,3/12,4/13,5/14,6/15}
 {
    \draw (\x,0) circle (7pt);
    \draw (\x,0) node {$\y$};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I could easily exploit the fact that tikz chooses an appropiate center so that

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {10,11,...,15}
 {
    \draw (\x,0) circle (7pt);
    \draw (\x,0) node {$\x$}; 
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

works just as well. But if I don't want to use this exploit, and try

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {1/10,2/11,...,6/15}
 {
    \draw (\x,0) circle (7pt);
    \draw (\x,0) node {$\y$};
 }  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get a bunch of errors, beginning with

`Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [ }]`

Two questions: it is possible to iterate over several variables in a list (let's assume the lists are large enough that it's not feasible to do each of the cases by hand as above), and what's causing the error?

Thanks

Comment: If one of the variables is sequential and starts at 1 (like the first in your case) you can use the `count`: `\foreach [count=\x] \y in {10,11,...,15}{\draw (\x,0) circle (7pt);\draw (\x,0) node {$\y$};}`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How to iterate `\foreach` with two variables and a list of values](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287055/5764).

Comment: @Werner Which might be a duplicate of [Possible to combine "..." and "x/y" in TikZ's foreach?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37601).

Comment: @Werner Not really; that doesn't have a solution, and the code/question is pretty convoluted.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. 's link is what I'm looking for though. The question of why the error arises still stands though.

Comment: @CookieMonster The boring answer is probably "because `pgf` isn't coded to support that syntax". So would you agree that we can close as a duplicate of my question?

Comment: @CookieMonster: Not having a solution has no bearing on whether something is a duplicate or not; the system just doesn't allow for closure of a question of another without the target having answers. Additionally, if the question is convoluted but asks the same thing, it's *the same thing*.

Comment: Your error arises because you're placing a measurement or digit into some syntax, and this syntax doesn't expect `...`; something a mixed-variable `\foreach` can't handle.